# Get field value directly from inside views-view-list.tpl.php

Tags: views, entities, theming

Inside `views-view-list.tpl.php` there is a loop like this:

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <li class="<?php print $classes_array[$id]; ?>"><?php print $row; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I want to be able to access the actual values of the fields inside each item, rather than passing off the rendering of the html to `views-view-fields.tpl.php`.

In pseudocode, I would like to do this (THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK):

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <?php print $row->$fields['field_my_field_name']; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <?php print $row->$fields['field_my_second_field_name']; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Would I actually use the `$row` object, or would I use something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> views-view-list.tpl.php file it's a view template to display a list of
>   rows, not fields.

**Theming only fields:**

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
    <li><?php print $field->content; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

** file: views-view-fields--[view name]--[display].tpl.php*

**Theming the whole output:**

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($view->style_plugin->rendered_fields as $delta => $item): ?>
        <li><?php print $item['field_my_field_name']; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

** file: views-view--[view name]--[display].tpl.php*

Answer (score 3):

took me a while to work this out so sharing the solution i used.

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
    <?php print $view->render_field('field_my_field_name', $id);?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
    <?php print $view->render_field('field_my_second_field_name', $id);?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Why is this not working! I am wondering how it got three votes

Answer (score 1):

There is a `$view` variable inside most Views templates that contains the entire View Object.  Inside of it, you can access the raw results via `$view->result` which is basically an array of the rows.  Throwing in a `drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($view->result, TRUE) . '</pre>')` or equivalent will give you an idea of what you have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is : $fields["field_name"]->content; Where field_name -> cck field name.

Hope that will help !!

Cheers ! Raj